# How do I create a custom Year/Week field in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to extend a CalendarDate table in one of our systems because the initial table only had dates up to the end of 2019. (I know...)

The issue is that one of the fields is a week field for our client that is in the format YYYYXX, where XX is a counter of week (ie 01 - 52).

The problem I am encountering is that there is a corresponding DayOfWeek field where Saturday is 1, and the week in the problem column increments on a Saturday, whereas in SQL Server it seems that `DATEPART(WEEK, @Date)` increments on a Sunday.

Using a temporary table of dates from today until 2030, is there any way I can compute this column?

One caveat is that the column must contain 52 full weeks per year. This means, for example, that the week `202001` in this column actually started on 2019-12-28, so I cannot simply get the year component from `DATEPART(YEAR, @date)`

Here is what I have so far (`#TempDates` is just a table with list of dates from today onward):

```
SELECT
    10 AS TrackingGroupID,
    CAST([Date] AS DATETIME) AS CalendarDate,
    NULL AS RetailerWeek,
    CAST(CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
        + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, Date)), 3) AS INT) AS DateID,
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date), 1, 3)) AS DayOfWeek,
    CASE UPPER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date), 1, 3))
        WHEN 'SAT' THEN 1
        WHEN 'SUN' THEN 2
        WHEN 'MON' THEN 3
        WHEN 'TUE' THEN 4
        WHEN 'WED' THEN 5
        WHEN 'THU' THEN 6
        WHEN 'FRI' THEN 7
        END AS DayOfWeekID,

    -- This is the column that needs fixing
    CAST(CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(WEEK, Date)), 2) AS INT) AS RetailerWeek2
FROM
    #TempDates
```

Comment: Eh. But how do you want to deal with leap years / years with 53 weeks?

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Saturday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to create date dimension.
This contains the week for every day.
You can generate the week as you wish.

```
/*Creación de la tabla*/

create table Dimensiones.Fecha
(
    FechaSK int not null, 
    Fecha date not null,  
    Año smallint not null, 
    Trimestre smallint not null, 
    Mes smallint not null,
    Semana smallint not null,
    Dia smallint not null,
    DiaSemana smallint not null,
    NTrimestre char(12) not null,
    NMes char(15) not null,
    NMes3L char(3) not null,
    NSemana char(10) not null,
    NDia char(6) not null,
    NDiaSemana char(10) not null
    constraint PK_DIM_TIEMPO PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        Fecha asc
    )
)
/*Script de carga*/
DECLARE @FechaDesde as smalldatetime, @FechaHasta as smalldatetime
DECLARE @FechaAAAAMMDD int
DECLARE @Año as smallint, @Trimestre char(2), @Mes smallint
DECLARE @Semana smallint, @Dia smallint, @DiaSemana smallint
DECLARE @NTrimestre char(12), @NMes char(15)
DECLARE @NMes3l char(3)
DECLARE @NSemana char(10), @NDia char(6), @NDiaSemana char(10)
--Set inicial por si no coincide con los del servidor
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SET DATEFIRST 1
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    --Borrar datos actuales, si fuese necesario
    TRUNCATE TABLE  dimensiones.fecha

    --Rango de fechas a generar: del 01/01/1990 al 31/12/Año actual+2
    SELECT @FechaDesde = CAST('19900101' AS smalldatetime)
    --SELECT @FechaHasta = CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())+2 AS CHAR(4)) + '1231' AS smalldatetime)

    WHILE (@FechaDesde <= @FechaHasta) BEGIN
    SELECT @FechaAAAAMMDD = YEAR(@FechaDesde)*10000+
                            MONTH(@FechaDesde)*100+
                            DATEPART(dd, @FechaDesde)
    SELECT @Año = DATEPART(yy, @FechaDesde)
    SELECT @Trimestre = DATEPART(qq, @FechaDesde)
    SELECT @Mes = DATEPART(m, @FechaDesde)
    SELECT @Semana = DATEPART(wk, @FechaDesde)
    SELECT @Dia = RIGHT('0' + DATEPART(dd, @FechaDesde),2)
    SELECT @DiaSemana = DATEPART(DW, @FechaDesde)
    SELECT @NMes = DATENAME(mm, @FechaDesde)
    SELECT @NMes3l = LEFT(@NMes, 3)
    SELECT @NTrimestre = 'Trimestre ' + CAST(@Trimestre as CHAR(1))
    SELECT @NSemana = 'Sem ' +CAST(@Semana AS CHAR(2)) + '/' + RIGHT(RTRIM(CAST(@Año as CHAR(4))),2)
    SELECT @NDia = CAST(@Dia as CHAR(2)) + ' ' + RTRIM(@NMes)
    SELECT @NDiaSemana = DATENAME(dw, @FechaDesde)
    INSERT INTO Dimensiones.Fecha
    ( 
        FechaSK,
        Fecha,
        Año, 
        Trimestre, 
        Mes,
        Semana,
        Dia,
        DiaSemana,
        NTrimestre,
        NMes,
        NMes3L,
        NSemana,
        NDia,
        NDiaSemana
    ) VALUES
    (
        @FechaAAAAMMDD,
        @FechaDesde,
        @Año,
        @Trimestre,
        @Mes,
        @Semana,
        @Dia,
        @DiaSemana,
        @NTrimestre,
        @NMes,
        @NMes3l,
        @NSemana,
        @NDia,
        @NDiaSemana
    )

    --Incremento del bucle
    SELECT @FechaDesde = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FechaDesde)
    END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the DATEFIRST to 6 then a week starts on saturday.

Then by using a `CASE WHEN` the year & week can be adjusted.

```
...
CAST(
    CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(week, [Date]) > 52
    THEN (100*(YEAR([Date])+1))+1
    ELSE (100* YEAR([Date])) + DATEPART(week, [Date])
    END AS VARCHAR(6)) as RetailerWeek2
...
```

**Example:**

> ```
> SET DATEFIRST 6; -- 6: Saturday
> SELECT @@DATEFIRST AS datefirst;
>
> SELECT [Date]
> , DATEPART(week, [Date]) as WeekNr
> , DATEPART(dw, [Date]) as WeekdayNr
> , CAST(
> CASE 
> WHEN DATEPART(week, [Date]) > 52
> THEN (100*(YEAR([Date])+1))+1
> ELSE (100* YEAR([Date])) + DATEPART(week, [Date])
> END AS VARCHAR(6)) as AdjustedYearWeek
> FROM (VALUES
> (CAST('2019-12-28' AS DATE)),
> (CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE)),
> (CAST('2020-12-31' AS DATE))
> ) q([Date]);
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | datefirst |
> | :-------- |
> | 6         |
>
> Date                | WeekNr | WeekdayNr | AdjustedYearWeek
> :------------------ | -----: | --------: | :---------------
> 28/12/2019 00:00:00 |     53 |         1 | 202001          
> 01/01/2020 00:00:00 |      1 |         5 | 202001          
> 31/12/2020 00:00:00 |     53 |         6 | 202101
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=abdae3005a2e529094a851f3a93d8625)*